# Sort different lists in the same sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three different stripes and I need to sort them by 'num'

```
cod = []
desc = []
num =[]

cod.append("1")
desc.append("Product1")
num.append(94)

cod.append("2")
desc.append("Product2")
num.append(93)

cod.append("3")
desc.append("Product3")
num.append(95)

for row in range(len(cod)):
    print(cod[row], desc[row], num[row])
```

The result I want to get is this

```
3 Product3 95
1 Product1 94
2 Product2 93
```

I tried using `num.sort()` but it didn't work

Comment: You did not link anyhow the lists, they are different objects. How do expect that sorting one would modify the others?

Comment: @Fra93 How can I link them?

Comment: This is in the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id51).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cod = []
desc = []
num =[]

cod.append("1")
desc.append("Product1")
num.append(94)

cod.append("2")
desc.append("Product2")
num.append(93)

cod.append("3")
desc.append("Product3")
num.append(95)

zipped = list(zip(num, cod, desc))
zipped.sort()

num, desc, cod = zip(*zipped)

for row in range(len(cod)):
    print(cod[row], desc[row], num[row])
```

Output:

```
Product2 2 93
Product1 1 94
Product3 3 95
```

Comment: It's only sorting ascending. How does it change to descending?

Comment: Use `zipped.sort(reverse=True)` if you want descending order

Comment: @Brandalize Why is this answer accepted when it doesn't produce the required output?

Comment: Why not ? @OldBill

Comment: @Brandalize The output of this answer differs from the output required in your question

Comment: @Oldbill it's just the print order that is not the same. It's not that important.

Comment: @OldBill
The fix is in the comment above. Isn't that valid too? I'm new here

Comment: @Aymen the desired output is 99% of problem solving.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get your desired output by putting the lists into a list of lists and then sorting by the num element

```
cod = []
desc = []
num =[]
L = []
cod.append("1")
desc.append("Product1")
num.append(94)

cod.append("2")
desc.append("Product2")
num.append(93)

cod.append("3")
desc.append("Product3")
num.append(95)

[L.append([cod[row], desc[row], num[row]]) for row in range(len(cod))]
    
L.sort(key=lambda sublist: sublist[2], reverse=True)

[print(*i) for i in L]
```

Output:

```
3 Product3 95
1 Product1 94
2 Product2 93
```

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that you want to sort (in reverse) on the values in *num* although the sub-sorts are unclear. However, this will give the required output:

```
cod = ['1', '2', '3']
desc = ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3']
num = [94, 93, 95]

for n, d, c in sorted(zip(num, desc, cod), reverse=True):
    print(c, d, n)
```

**Output:**

```
3 Product3 95
1 Product1 94
2 Product2 93
```

Answer (score 0):

Managing three separate lists is cumbersome and should be avoided. I changed it up a bit and created a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) that encapsulates all the data per product.
The [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__str__) method is overloaded to produce the same result as your required output.
The sorting is the same as @stefan_aus_hannover's but with a bit better readability (it uses the `.number` member instead of the index 2 of a sublist).
There is also an option to use in-place [sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list%20sort#list.sort) of the list

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Product:
    code: str
    description: str
    number: int
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.code} {self.description} {self.number}'

products = [
Product(code='1',description='Product1',number=94),
Product(code='2',description='Product2',number=93),
Product(code='3',description='Product3',number=95),
]

# EITHER create a new sorted list
products = sorted(products,key=lambda p: p.number, reverse=True)
# OR sort in place
products.sort(key=lambda p: p.number, reverse=True)

for prod in products:
    print(prod)
```

Output:

```
3 Product3 95
1 Product1 94
2 Product2 93
```